# Multiple polling request on updating socket.io to 1.0 version (HTTP Error 400)

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, newrelic

I was using node.js along with socket.io, which was working properly till now.
After updating the socket.io to latest version of 1.0 the following issue has come to my notice.

1] I was continuously getting error "HTTP Error 400" in new relic, I am unable to trace why this error come
    Please help me....

2] I am getting multiple polling requests which are of the type GET, whose response comes as NULL.
    When I try to open the URL of that GET request, following response is returned:
    Output
    {"code":3,"message":"Bad request"}

Following are the requests that I see in my firebug console:

```
GET http://yourdomain.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412592572238-0                                 200 OK  463ms   
GET http://yourdomain.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412592572811-1&sid=HCVdC05LuQyBNpTMACcY        200 OK  241ms   
GET http://yourdomain.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412592573093-3&sid=HCVdC05LuQyBNpTMACcY        200 OK  566ms   
GET http://yourdomain.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412592573674-4&sid=HCVdC05LuQyBNpTMACcY        200 OK  291ms   
GET http://yourdomain.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412592573976-5&sid=HCVdC05LuQyBNpTMACcY        200 OK  285ms   
GET http://yourdomain.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412592574273-6&sid=HCVdC05LuQyBNpTMACcY        200 OK  289ms   
GET http://yourdomain.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412592574573-7&sid=HCVdC05LuQyBNpTMACcY        200 OK  292ms   
GET http://yourdomain.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412592574877-8&sid=HCVdC05LuQyBNpTMACcY        200 OK  934ms   
GET http://yourdomain.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412592575947-9&sid=HCVdC05LuQyBNpTMACcY        200 OK  256ms   
POST http://yourdomain.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412592575853-10&sid=HCVdC05LuQyBNpTMACcY      200 OK  311ms
```

Comment: NOTE: Apps using `v0.9.X or lower are not at all compatible with `v0.10.x or above`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be useful to run a test to see how your application behaves with New Relic disabled. Could you tell us if these errors still appear after you have disabled the agent? I see you have already contacted us at support.newrelic.com. Since we have already given a more detailed response there, I feel that would be a better place to continue the discussion.

The issue can be found here: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/multiple-polling-request-on-updating-socket-io-to-1-0-version-http-error-400/8783